# Call a Custom Class Method from jQuery/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, visual-studio-2015

I am creating an eCommerce website for school in Visual Studio 15. I am using jQuery and a handler to display the products retrieved from my database. Doing it this way I am unsure how to call methods from my shopping cart class that I wrote within the `<script>` tag. Each product has this button:

```
<button type=\"button\" data-itemID=\"" + dt.Rows[i]["itemID"] + 
                      "\" class=\"btnAddItem\">Add To Cart</button>
```

I'm trying to bind a click event to each button to call my method `Add(itemID)`, I understand I could do it a lot easier just using C# but I already wrote my jQuery and handler.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
    $("button.btnAddItem").on('click', function(){
      Add($(this).attr('data-itemID');
    });
```

The jquery selector ( the thing in $() ) matches all buttons with the class "btnAddItem", and then once clicked, fires an anonymous function that calls Add() with the data-itemID attribute form the button that was clicked. This can also be achieved without an anonymous function:

```
    function buttonClickHandler(event){
      Add($(this).attr('data-itemID'));
    };

    $("button.newAddItem").on('click', buttonClickHandler);
```

Hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

I assume thet method `Add(itemId)` is written in C#, in Controller named Home.

```
class Home : Controller {
    public ActionResult Add(string itemId) //...
}
```

Every item in controller is by default mapped to GET and POST http request. So what you can do is call your method from jQuery with GET like so:

```
$.get( "/Home/Add" , {itemId: "test"} ,function( data ) {
  $( ".result" ).html( data );
  alert( "Add was performed." );
});
```

or with POST:

```
var responce = $.post("/Home/Add",
{
    itemId: "test",
},
function () {
    console.log(responce);
    ...
});
```

And now for connecting to the button event, you can use jquery method in your script:

```
$("button.addItemButton").on('click', function()
{
  var responce = $.post("/Home/Add", ///rest of the code...
});
```

Comment: My method is inside my own shopping cart class, not in Controller. I might just scrap the jQuery and do it all in C#

Comment: The class is written in C# though?

Comment: Oh ok, but the principle stays the same, what you need to do is expose your method to Controller :)

Comment: @DylanSowtis Please accept one of the anwsers if you think they solved your problem.